# jQuery get text value from elements from different divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading item-name">T-shirt1</div>
    <div class="panel-body"><img src="img/shirt1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <h5>PRICE: <span class="old-price">$15.32</span></h5>
        <h4>$17.56</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading item-name">T-shirt2</div>
    <div class="panel-body"><img src="img/shirt2.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt="Image"></div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <h5>PRICE: <span class="old-price">$21.67</span></h5>
        <h4>$23.15</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading item-name">T-shirt3</div>
    <div class="panel-body"><img src="img/shirt3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <h5>PRICE: <span class="old-price">$16.69</span></h5>
        <h4>$16.80</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I really want is to retrieve the value of each item-name when I click on the Add to cart button. If I click on the first button, I should get `T-shirt1`, second button should alert `T-shirt2`, third button => `T-shirt3`.

Here is my jQuery script.

```
<script>

$('.add-to-cart').click(function() {
    var itemName = $('.item-name', this).text();
    alert(itemName);
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).closest('.panel').find('.item-name').text();
    alert(itemName);
});
```

Usage of the `closest` method: [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Go from clicked button up in parents chain until you find `.panel` and then down in children tree until you find `.item.name`:

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).parents('.panel').children('.item-name').first().text();
    alert(itemName);
});
```